# Type month of html not allowing to fetch dynamic dates from database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, input, monthcalendar

I am using `type=month` for input value. I have finished storing data into db but on the time of fetching data its not showing my db's date on form.

```
SELECT * ,DATE_FORMAT(end_date, '%M  %Y') AS endDate FROM vat_report
```

I am using above format to fetch date. If I `echo endDate` it shows me proper date like January 2018, February 2019 etc whatever is in the database but on input box its not showing data. If I change type = `month` to type = `text` then it is displaying my date. But I only want `month` type on input box so that on update too user can update date in M-Y format.

```
<td><input type="month" name="end_date"  value="<?php echo $end_date1;?>"/></td>
```

Above is my html code for showing date in month name - year format. I can't find any solution for this. It shows only some `------   ----` something like this inside input box

Comment: My suggestion would be to handle formatting in application code.

Comment: I wasn't aware that month was a type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that if you `echo endDate` it shows you the proper date like "January 2019". Don't you mean `echo $endDate` instead?

In your inline PHP, you do `<?php echo $end_date1;?>`, could the issue be that you added a `1` to the end?

If you only want to show the month, you should use `SELECT * ,DATE_FORMAT(end_date, '%M') AS endDate FROM vat_report`

Comment: i checked with everything but it wont allow me to display date on type month. its working on type text. $end_date1 is my variable

Answer (score 0):

You should add a format like `->format('Y-m')` in the value field (ex. `value="2017-06"`)